# HTML5 Ajax to a different domain?

Tags: ajax, html

I recently came across http://chromeexperiments.com/. I found a couple of projects there that are quite intriguing: 100 Tweets and twitterbrowse (I'd post links to them but I'm not yet allowed). These both work fine for me in Firefox 3.5 under Ubuntu 9.04. The thing that I find particularly peculiar is the fact that these two "experiments" seem to issue Ajax requests to other domains than the ones they are hosted on (to twitter.com, more exactly). I have tried the same thing on an HTML5 page (using `<!DOCTYPE html>`), but I can't get it to work.

I'm using MooTools to create the requests, but that shouldn't be a problem, it's still Ajax, right?

Any idea how those sites are doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj/

I personnaly was able to do this using the JSON method on a personal project where I had to receive ajax response from a different domain's server.

Comment: Indeed. I looked through jQuery's source and realized it checks if the request is made to another domain and in that case it dynamically creates a <script> tag and loads it in that.

Comment: so how does this answer html5 ajax to another domain? this merely shows the workarounds of old, before html5.

Answer (score 5):

XMLHttpRequest Level 2 allows for cross-domain AJAX. Read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#differences).

Comment: Thank you for the link, very interesting. Unfortunately, that document does not specify in which conditions a cross-domain request can be issued. I also doubt that XMLHttpRequest L2 has been implemented so far in any browser.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't using HTML5 for the ajax request, they're using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which is essentially a getter for JSON, but can be made across any domain